# Why is `pam_nologin.so` denying access despite no existence of `/etc/nologin`?

Tags: pam, etc, nologin

After [A lot of searching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353629/access-denied-by-pam-account-configuration-despite-configured-access-conf-and-up/1353834#1353834), I managed to debug a PAM configuration file, and it turns out the `pam_nologin.so` module was denying access to my system. Now, this is particularly strange since, according to the man page, it should only deny access to non-root users when the `/etc/nologin` file exists, and this file has never existed on my system (checked with both `rm` and `ls`), as I have verified multiple times throughout this experience. Is there any other condition that could be causing this?

Comment: If pam_nologin, is causing this, then grep for it in the pam conf files. Remember, pam_nologin can be specified with an alternative name.

Comment: If by "grepping it in the conf files" you mean disabling the module on the confs that have issues, I'm doing that temporarily, but it isn't an ideal long-term solution. Also, what do you mean pam_nologin can be specified with an alternative name?

Comment: From the pam_nologin man page, an alternative nologin file can be specified... `pam_nologin.so [file=/path/nologin]`.

Comment: I'd prefer if that wasn't the only option, since that would imply either keeping two different yet unrelated nologin files, or specifying that file on every single nologin module.